# Cannot access org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository in sub module of multi module maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have spring boot project and while using jpa I faced following error in sub module of multi module maven project and clould not found any solution :

```
Cannot access org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
```

How can I solve this isssue?

Answer (score 1):

- You can add your spring-jpa lib into the submodule's pom.xml
- Or you can Override methods that you want to use in the submodule like this so that submodule no need to import spring-jpa package

https://i.stack.imgur.com/udWcX.png